# How To Achieve the desired Design in uicollection view using decorator view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewflowlayout

See the following boarder of the each items (Border Spacing)

[image]

With collection view Header I am able to achieve the following out put but stuck at how to put separator inside the uicollection view. also the number of cell inside the row is dynamic.

and last row should not the the bottom separator
any help is really appreciate..

For Achieving  the following layout i only use the collection view with section header 
I have already done the following output

All section are collapsed

[image]
clicked on particular secttion

[image]

Just the separator part is remaining for each expanded section
I cant figure out how can i achieve the same using decoration view.

Comment: Use a decorator view? That, for example, is how those "shelves" in iBooks were achieved.

Comment: can you please post link or demo exapmle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it like this,

- Create two different types of decoration view, one for vertical line which is at the center of the collection view and other being horizontal which appear below two cell
- Vertical decoration view is created only once for the whole view, while horizontal decoration view is created for a pair of two which appears below each row. For the last row, dont create the decoration view.
- subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout, and override *override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?* and return appropriate decoration view.

Here is how the layout looks for me,

[image]

And here is the code used for that,

**CollectionViewController**,

```
class ViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    let images = ["Apple", "Banana", "Grapes", "Mango", "Orange", "Strawberry"]

     init() {
        let collectionViewLayout = DecoratedFlowLayout()
        collectionViewLayout.register(HorizontalLineDecorationView.self,
                                      forDecorationViewOfKind: HorizontalLineDecorationView.decorationViewKind)
        collectionViewLayout.register(VerticalLineDecorationView.self,
                                      forDecorationViewOfKind: VerticalLineDecorationView.decorationViewKind)
        super.init(collectionViewLayout: collectionViewLayout)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        collectionView?.register(CollectionViewCell.self,
                                 forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CollectionViewCell.CellIdentifier)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return images.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CollectionViewCell.CellIdentifier,
                                                      for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        let name = images[indexPath.item]
        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(name).png")
        cell.label.text = name
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return .zero
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10 + DecoratedFlowLayout.horizontalLineWidth
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let width = (collectionView.bounds.size.width - DecoratedFlowLayout.verticalLineWidth)  * 0.5
        return CGSize(width: width,
                      height: width + 20)
    }
}
```

**CollectionViewCell**,

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    static let CellIdentifier = "CollectionViewCellIdentifier"

    var imageView: UIImageView!
    var label: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        createViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func createViews() {
        imageView = UIImageView(frame: .zero)
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(imageView)

        label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(label)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor),
            imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
            label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor),
            label.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor),
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.bottomAnchor),
            label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20)
            ])
    }
}
```

**DecoratedFlowLayout**,

```
class DecoratedFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    static let verticalLineWidth: CGFloat = 20
    static let horizontalLineWidth: CGFloat = 20

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        minimumLineSpacing = 40 // should be equal to or greater than horizontalLineWidth 
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
        minimumLineSpacing = 40
   }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

        guard let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) else {
            return nil
        }

        var attributesCopy: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []

        for attribute in attributes {

            attributesCopy += [attribute]

            let indexPath = attribute.indexPath

            if collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: indexPath.section) == 0 {
                continue
            }

            let firstCell = IndexPath(item: 0,
                                      section: indexPath.section)
            let lastCell = IndexPath(item: collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1,
                                     section: indexPath.section)

            if let attributeForFirstItem = layoutAttributesForItem(at: firstCell),
                let attributeForLastItem = layoutAttributesForItem(at: lastCell) {


                let verticalLineDecorationView = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forDecorationViewOfKind: VerticalLineDecorationView.decorationViewKind,
                                                                                  with: IndexPath(item: 0, section: indexPath.section))

                let firstFrame = attributeForFirstItem.frame
                let lastFrame = attributeForLastItem.frame

                let frame = CGRect(x: collectionView!.bounds.midX - DecoratedFlowLayout.verticalLineWidth * 0.5,
                                   y: firstFrame.minY,
                                   width: DecoratedFlowLayout.verticalLineWidth,
                                   height: lastFrame.maxY - firstFrame.minY)
                verticalLineDecorationView.frame =  frame

                attributesCopy += [verticalLineDecorationView]
            }


            let contains = attributesCopy.contains { layoutAttribute in
                layoutAttribute.indexPath == indexPath
                    && layoutAttribute.representedElementKind == HorizontalLineDecorationView.decorationViewKind
            }

            let numberOfItemsInSection = collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: indexPath.section)

            if indexPath.item % 2 == 0 && !contains  && indexPath.item < numberOfItemsInSection - 2 {

                let horizontalAttribute = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forDecorationViewOfKind: HorizontalLineDecorationView.decorationViewKind,
                                                                           with: indexPath)

                let frame = CGRect(x: attribute.frame.minX,
                                   y: attribute.frame.maxY + (minimumLineSpacing - DecoratedFlowLayout.horizontalLineWidth) * 0.5,
                                   width: collectionView!.bounds.width,
                                   height: DecoratedFlowLayout.horizontalLineWidth)

                horizontalAttribute.frame = frame

                attributesCopy += [horizontalAttribute]
            }
        }
        return attributesCopy
    }

    override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

**And decoration views**

```
class VerticalLineDecorationView: UICollectionReusableView {

    static let decorationViewKind = "VerticalLineDecorationView"

    let verticalInset: CGFloat = 40

    let lineWidth: CGFloat = 4.0

    let lineView = UIView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        lineView.backgroundColor = .black

        addSubview(lineView)

        lineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            lineView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: lineWidth),
            lineView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: verticalInset),
            lineView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -verticalInset),
            lineView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
            ])
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}


class HorizontalLineDecorationView: UICollectionReusableView {

    let horizontalInset: CGFloat = 20

    let lineWidth: CGFloat = 4.0

    static let decorationViewKind = "HorizontalLineDecorationView"

    let lineView = UIView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        lineView.backgroundColor = .black

        addSubview(lineView)

        lineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            lineView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: lineWidth),
            lineView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: horizontalInset),
            lineView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -horizontalInset),
            lineView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            ])
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I hope you can make use of it and tweak values to suit your own need. Some of the calculations might make sense to change to some level. But, I hope you get the idea about how this could be achieved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167454/discussion-between-jaydeep-vyas-and-sandeep).

Comment: @Sandeep does this answer solve my problem asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53743467/adding-in-static-cells-in-between-dynamic-collectionview-cells-swift/53743875#53743875

Answer (score 0):

If the number of columns is always 2, why don't you add three views(separators) to a cell, two on the sides and one on the bottom. For the cells on the right side, hide the right most separator and vice versa for cells on the left.
Hide the separator on the bottom for cells on the last row. 
It is a bit of a hack but much simpler to implement.

Comment: i know that i have already implemented that but i want to use the decorator view

Answer (score 0):

customize `UICollectionviewcell` (I think you might already have done that),
Now on custom `UICollectionviewcell` put two UIView -

- one `UIView` at the right of the cell with 1 or 2 point width(as per
  required) and height equals to cell height, give a black background
  color to `UIView`.
- Another `UIView` at the bottom of the cell with 1 or 2 point height(as per required) and this time width equals to cell width, give a black background color to `UIView`. 
  and adjust the spaces.
  I thing this trick will work for you.